# Updating child model with same data as parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have four models related to each other as below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :clients
    has_many :default_prices
end

class DefaultPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :client_prices
    has_many :clients, :through => :user
    belongs_to :user
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :client_prices
    before_create do
        user.default_prices.each do |default_price|
            client_prices.build("price" => default_price.price, "visit_type" => default_price.visit_type, "default_price_id" => default_price.id)
        end
    end
end

class ClientPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    belongs_to :default_price
end
```

Right now when a new client is created by the user, the user's default prices are applied to the client's client_prices table. How can I have new client_prices (for each existing client) created when new default_prices are created by the user? Also, how can I have the client_prices update when the default prices are changed? Each client prices has an default_price_id column that relates to the default price, if that helps.

Comment: you might implement this via hooks, such as after_save hook  of AR, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class DefaultPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :new_client_price
  before_update :update_clients_price

private
    def new_client_price
  clients.each do |c|
    self.client_prices.create(:price => self.price, :visit_type => self.visit_type, :client_id => c.id)
        end
end

def update_clients_price
  self.client_prices.each do |p|
      p.price = self.price
        p.visit_type = self.visit_type
      p.save
  end
end
```

Comment: This is great, I've added in some logic to iterate through each client and so it adds in the client_id column.